# Get Entities that fulfill predicate even some have null object for parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to fetch records for NSFetchReultController using predicate

```
NSNumber *project_id=[[_options objectForKey:@"project"] objectForKey:@"server_id"];

predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(owner.user_id = %@ OR  Any jarSharedToUsers.user_id = %@) AND status = %@ AND  parentProject.project_id = %@ ",user.user_id,user.user_id,[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],project_id];
```

**Error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath parentProject.project_id not found in entity '**

i think this is due to parentProject is null for some entities. but then how i get the entites who fulfil the predicate

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually thrown if you try to access a property of an NSManagedObject that does not exist. Did you recheck your dataModel? Is the relationship from project to parentProject set correctly? Does the parentProject have an entity called project_id?

Did you update your NSManagedObject classes after you changed your DataModel?

And also: Did you completely erase the app from your device (or reset the simulator if you use that) after you changed your dataModel? Changes to dataModel are only applied to clean builds or if you use a migration model.

Comment: the problem is that some NSManagedObject had a relation and some donot have that relations.